# TypeError when creating shapefile from the intersection of shapefiles with PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, shapefile, polygon, intersection, typeerror

I have two polygons (*'anlage'* and *'natur'*). I want to create a new shapefile from the intersection of these two shapefiles.

The created shapefile has an attribute table of the same size as the attribute table of *'anlage'*. If there is an intersection, the attribute table of output gets name and area fields from *'anlage'* attribute table and name1 and name2 from *'natur'* for its attribute table. If there is no intersection, it gets only name and area fields from *'anlage'*. This is my code:

```py
import processing
from qgis.core import QgsVectorFileWriter
from qgis.core import QgsFields

# Load the anlage and natur shapefiles
anlage = QgsVectorLayer("C:/shapefile/2/anlage.shp", "anlage", "ogr")
natur = QgsVectorLayer("C:/shapefile/2/natur.shp", "natur", "ogr")

# Create the new shapefile by intersecting anlage and natur
intersection = processing.run("native:intersection", {'INPUT':anlage, 'OVERLAY':natur, 'OUTPUT':'memory:'})['OUTPUT']

# Create an empty list to store the new field names and types
fields = []

# Add the "name" and "area" fields from the anlage attribute table
fields.append(QgsField("name", QVariant.String))
fields.append(QgsField("area", QVariant.Double))

# Check if the intersection is not empty
if intersection.featureCount() > 0:
    # Add the "name1" and "name2" fields from the natur attribute table
    fields.append(QgsField("name1", QVariant.String))
    fields.append(QgsField("name2", QVariant.String))

# Create the new shapefile and set the fields
crs = anlage.crs()
writer = QgsVectorFileWriter("C:/shapefile/2/new_shapefile.shp", "CP1250", fields, QgsWkbTypes.Polygon, crs, "ESRI Shapefile")

# Add the features from the intersection to the new shapefile
for feature in intersection.getFeatures():
    writer.addFeature(feature)

# Close the writer and add the new shapefile to the QGIS project
del writer
new_shapefile = QgsVectorLayer("C:/shapefile/2/new_shapefile.shp", "new_shapefile", "ogr")
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(new_shapefile)
```

but PyQGIS returns this error:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.13\apps\Python39\lib\code.py", line 90, in runcode
>     exec(code, self.locals)
>   File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
>   File "<string>", line 26, in <module>
> TypeError: QgsVectorFileWriter(): argument 3 has unexpected type 'list'
> ```

Could anyone help me to fix this?

Comment: Please, do not forget about ["What should I do when someone answers my question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 3):

[image] Using [`QgsVectorFileWriter`](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsVectorFileWriter.html#aef8a52d9c8e2b9c287f32948cdee71d6) constructor is deprecated. Use [`QgsVectorFileWriter.create()`](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsVectorFileWriter.html#a141e30147889db7abb21d09ce775e5fc) as follows:

```py
...

options = QgsVectorFileWriter.SaveVectorOptions()
options.driverName = "ESRI Shapefile"
options.fileEncoding = "CP1250"

QgsVectorFileWriter.create(
    "C:/shapefile/2/new_shapefile.shp",
    fields, 
    QgsWkbTypes.Polygon,
    crs,
    QgsCoordinateTransformContext(),
    options
)
```

This solves the current error, but you may get another error.

**Edit**: The second argument expects a `QgsFields` instance, but you define `fields` as a list. Change `fields = []` to `fields = QgsFields()`.

Comment: unfortunatly  get this error: TypeError: QgsVectorFileWriter.create(): argument 2 has unexpected type 'list'

Comment: I missed `fields=QgsFields()` and `SaveVectorOptions()`. Please check the answer again.